# How to count frequency of a multiword expression in Quanteda?

Tags: r, quanteda

I am trying to count the frequency of a multiword expression in Quanteda. I know several articles in the corpus contain this expression, as when I look for it using 're' in Python it can find them. However, with Quanteda it doesn't seem to be working. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
> mwes <- phrase(c("抗美 援朝"))
> tc <- tokens_compound(toks_NK, mwes, concatenator = "")
> dfm <- dfm(tc, select="抗美援朝")
> dfm
Document-feature matrix of: 2,337 documents, 0 features and 7 docvars.
[ reached max_ndoc ... 2,331 more documents ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but **quanteda**'s default tokenizer seems to separate the tokens in your phrase into four characters:

```
> tokens("抗美 援朝")
Tokens consisting of 1 document.
text1 :
[1] "抗" "美" "援" "朝"
```

For these reasons, you should consider an alternative tokenizer.  Fortunately the excellent spaCy Python library offers a means to do this, and has Chinese language models.  Using the **spacyr** package and **quanteda**, you can create tokens directly from the output of `spacyr::spacy_tokenize()` after loading the small Chinese language model.

To count just these expressions, you can use a combination of `tokens_select()` and then `textstat_frequency()` on the dfm.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.0

txt <- "Forty-four Americans 抗美 援朝 have now taken the presidential oath. 
The words have been spoken during rising tides of prosperity 
and the still waters of peace. Yet, every so often the oath 抗美 援朝
is taken amidst gathering clouds and raging storms. At these moments, 
America has carried on not simply because of the skill or vision of those in high office, 
but because We the People 抗美 援朝 have remained faithful to the ideals of our forbearers, 
and true to our founding documents."

library("spacyr")
# spacy_download_langmodel("zh_core_web_sm") # only needs to be done once
spacy_initialize(model = "zh_core_web_sm")
## Found 'spacy_condaenv'. spacyr will use this environment
## successfully initialized (spaCy Version: 2.3.2, language model: zh_core_web_sm)
## (python options: type = "condaenv", value = "spacy_condaenv")

spacy_tokenize(txt) %>%
  as.tokens() %>%
  tokens_compound(pattern = phrase("抗美 援朝"), concatenator = " ") %>%
  tokens_select("抗美 援朝") %>%
  dfm() %>%
  textstat_frequency()
##     feature frequency rank docfreq group
## 1 抗美 援朝         3    1       1   all
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting: "Error: Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed?"

Comment: You have to install and configure **spacyr** first, see `?spacy_install`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. Can I run `spacy_tokenize` in the same way I would run `tokens()` on a corpus?

Comment: Yes, see `?spacy_tokenize`. It returns a named list, which can be converted to tokens using `quanteda::as.tokens()`, or processed into tokens with further options using `quanteda::tokens()`.

Comment: Thanks! One more q if I may? I'd been using `dfm(corp, select="feat" group="date")` to count features by date. Is there a way to do this, but with these new tokens included?

Comment: See the groups argument in textstat_frequency()

Answer (score 2):

First off, apologies for not being able to use a fully Chinese text. But here's presidential address into which I've taken the liberty of inserting your Mandarin words:

```
data <- "I stand here today humbled by the task before us 抗美 援朝, 
grateful for the trust you have bestowed, mindful of the sacrifices borne by our ancestors. 
I thank President Bush for his service to our nation, 
as well as the generosity and cooperation he has shown throughout this transition.

Forty-four Americans 抗美 援朝 have now taken the presidential oath. 
The words have been spoken during rising tides of prosperity 
and the still waters of peace. Yet, every so often the oath 抗美 援朝
is taken amidst gathering clouds and raging storms. At these moments, 
America has carried on not simply because of the skill or vision of those in high office, 
but because We the People 抗美 援朝 have remained faithful to the ideals of our forbearers, 
and true to our founding documents."
```

What you can do, if you want to use `quanteda`, is you can compute 4-grams (I take it your words consist of four signs and will hence be treated as four words)

Step 1: split text into word tokens:

```
data_tokens <- tokens(data, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE)
```

Step 2: compute 4-grams and make a frequency list of them

```
fourgrams <- sort(table(unlist(as.character(tokens_ngrams(data_tokens, n = 4, concatenator = " ")))), decreasing = T)
```

You can inspect the first ten:

```
fourgrams[1:10]

                抗 美 援 朝               美 援 朝 have      America has carried on          Americans 抗 美 援 
                          4                           2                           1                           1 
amidst gathering clouds and ancestors I thank President      and cooperation he has        and raging storms At 
                          1                           1                           1                           1 
       and the still waters             and true to our 
                          1                           1
```

If you just want to know the frequency of your target compound:

```
fourgrams["抗 美 援 朝"]
抗 美 援 朝 
         4
```

Alternatively, and much more simply, especially if your interest is really just in a single compound, you could use `str_extract_all` from `stringr`. This will provide you the frequency count immediately:

```
library(stringr)
length(unlist(str_extract_all(data, "抗美 援朝")))
[1] 4
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! However, I was hoping to count the freq of these multi word expression in each document of the corpus, i.e. in a 'document frequency matrix', not the overall frequency. 抗美援朝 is four words / tokens, which would appear in the text without any spaces between them or the other words. The method I wrote above works for combining 2 words / tokens, eg. 国际 (international) and 社会 (society) to make `mwes <- phrase(c("国际 社会“）)` but not for my 4-token phrase. If I try just two tokens ("抗 美“), it finds the mwe in 2/2500 articles, but Python finds in 10 docs

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it is the best to make a dictionary to lookup or compound tokens in Chinese or Japanese languages, but dictionary values should be segmented in the same way as tokens does.

```
require(quanteda)
require(stringi)

txt <- "10月初，聯合國軍逆轉戰情，向北開進，越過38度線，終促使中华人民共和国決定出兵介入，中国称此为抗美援朝。"
lis <- list(mwe1 = "抗美援朝", mwe2 = "向北開進")

## tokenize dictionary values
lis <- lapply(lis, function(x) stri_c_list(as.list(tokens(x)), sep = " "))
dict <- dictionary(lis)

## tokenize texts and count
toks <- tokens(txt)
dfm(tokens_lookup(toks, dict))
## Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 2 features (0.0% sparse).
##        features
## docs    mwe1 mwe2
##   text1    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm finding `tokens()` quite slow to tokenize a corpus of 200K Weibo 'tweets' ~ would you have any suggestions how I could speed it up?